# What is the value of the type?

Tags: haskell

I have following type declaration:

```
data MyType = MyVal Int deriving (Eq, Show)
```

As you can see, it has only one data type constructor with an argument.

In the book, it says:

> Because MyVal has one Int argument, a value of type MyType must
>   contain one — only one — Int value

Why is `Int` a value of type MyType or what does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't say that Int is of type `MyType`, it says that MyVal (constructor) must only contain an Int, so for example you can not do `MyVal "hey!"`

Check this

```
Prelude> data MyType = MyVal Int deriving (Eq, Show)
Prelude> :t MyVal 9
MyVal 9 :: MyType
Prelude> MyVal '9'

<interactive>:12:7: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Char’
    • In the first argument of ‘MyVal’, namely ‘'9'’
      In the expression: MyVal '9'
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = MyVal '9'
```

As you can see, the only way of using `MyVal` wich is of type `MyType` is with an `Int`, so no other type is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

To be super-explicit and clear, which is hopefully helpful: you said that "As you can see, it has only one data type constructor with an argument.", but I would adjust that slightly.

`data MyType = MyVal Int deriving (Eq, Show)`

Here `MyType` is the type. It's a **type constructor** with zero arguments, is one way of viewing it. Or, you could say it's the data type constructor.

However, `MyVal` is a **value constructor**. It's one of `MyType` data type's value constructors (which there are only one of in this example). That is, it's actually a function that constructs values of type `MyType`. So, `MyType` has **one value constructor called `MyVal` that takes one argument. That argument has type Int**.

If we ask GHCi what the type of this function is, it's clear its one argument is of type `Int`:

`Main> :t MyVal
MyVal :: Int -> MyType`

Why is it useful to "wrap" the type `Int` when it's already a type? One reason is that it separates the meaning of `MyVal` from `Int`, and you can thus have your own type, which is distinct from `Int` according to the type checker and your code, even though its representation happens to be an `Int` for now.

Maybe tomorrow you may decide to change it to an `Integer`, in which case all you probably have to do is change that one spot, and the rest of your code will work (assuming you don't use `Int` to refer to your unwrapped `MyVal`s, and that you have data access functions to deal with the base operations on the internal value of `MyVal`).

As an aside, just FYI, wrapping a single type in a `data` declaration like this is usually not done in professional code because it costs execution cycles to wrap and unwrap it. There's another way of declaring single-value types such as this, called `newtype` which gives a cost-free (at runtime) way to explain to the compiler and typechecker that you want a distinct value that has a representation as one of the existing values. I'm sure whatever book you're reading will explain this in due course, but if it doesn't, make a note to look these up later.